# NXT shuts down in 5 minutes

Tags: mindstorms, nxt

I have an NXT brick that will always shut down after 5 minutes. No, it is not the sleep timer. Documentation from the NXT Hardware SDK, page 17, states that if the ARM7 processor does not send back communication to the AVR microcontroller within 5 minutes of power up, it will shut down the ARM7. Here is the message: "\xCC" "Let's samba nxt arm in arm, (c) LEGO System A/S"

Has anyone had a 5 minute shut down problem not solved by resetting the sleep timer and have you solved it?

Comment: Is this "five minutes" measured while a program is running, or from the beginning of the NXT brick startup?

Comment: You might want to try updating the firmware on the NXT brick.

Answer (score 1):

I did not have that problem but I checked that error from programmer's perspective. The source seems to originate [here](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/cvsweb/cgi-bin/cvsweb/gforth/arch/arm/nxt/nxt_avr.c?rev=1.1;content-type=text%2Fplain) athough it can be also [found mirrored](https://github.com/earl/gforth-mirror) on GitHub where the complete package can be downloaded. After short analysis of few files it looks that the message you quoted is sent on re-initialized link (connection). The link is reinitialized automatically if its state is either uninitialized or failed.

If you can observe *exactly the same* time till each failure, then it looks this can be rather software issue than a hardware one. It can be still related to what you wrote in the question (one end of the link shut down after 5 minutes) or it can be related to some other software-based conditions. Try with trivial scenarios first. Also ensure that the firmware of all involved devices is up-to-date.

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured this out... It's broken!

Fried. Saw one do this after getting dropped. Never worked correctly again.

Sorry, man. Buy a new one, I guess. Nothing to be done here.